# Minimize the Logical Design

Tags: logic, computer-science, boolean-logic

i'm working for logical designs at the moment where i need to minimize the statement and than need to design the expression.

i have a statement that i need to minimize which is :
(x'+y+z+t)(x'+y'+z'+t)

i have to reduce that but  i dont think that i can minimize that, however
i know that if it was like only 1 parameter difference like this :
(x'+y'+z+t)(x'+y'+z'+t)

it will be equal to x'+y'+t with the boolean algebra, consensus and exc.
but i can't figure out if that can be minimized ?

hope you can help thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
A=(x'+t)
B=y+z
C=y'+z'
(x'+y+z+t)(x'+y'+z'+t) = (A+B)(A+C) == AA+AC+AB+BC = A+BC ==
(x'+t)+(y+z)(y'+z') = (x'+t)+(yz'+y'z) == (x'+t) + (y xor z)
```